# Read a file using javascript with JDK's Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

Am experimenting with Java's Rhino JavaScript engine.  I would like to be able to read a local file and store its contents as a string.   I see that there is a readFile function with the shell (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Shell), but I can't seem to be able to run readFile when being evaluated from a Java app.  I am using JDK1.6 and using the built in version of Rhino.  Any thoughts?  Here is what I have tried:

```
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("javascript");
        String jsCode = "var content=readFile('path_to_myFile');";
        jsCode+="println(content);";
        engine.eval(jsCode);
```

Comment: The Shell adds functionality like that to the global context of the interpreter. The ScriptEngine mechanism in Java gives you almost none of that stuff.

Comment: I guess a simple solution is to just have a utility class of java methods to accomplish the above, and then just call the java methods from javascript.  Perhaps a bit messy, but it works!

Comment: Yes that's what I've done. You can also write some JavaScript wrappers of your own, and then from the Java side you can "inject" them into the global context that subsequent JavaScript code will see.